# package not found while typing in apt-get install commands

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I'm newbie to Ubuntu and I'm working on the Ubuntu version 12.10, when i type in any command `apt-get install` i receive the message

```
package not found
```

thank you

Comment: Which package are you trying to install? Can you post an example of the command you're trying to run?

Comment: Normally, it should work with any package i tried apt-get install sl as a simple example

Comment: I got the message :" Impossible to find this package "

Comment: Then I don't know. Have you tried running "apt-get update" first?

Comment: yes, i tried with it and i receive many errors at the end i got ' downloading some index's files failed'

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 is end of life since May 2014, see also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Best path forward would be to upgrade to a supported release, for example a LTS release with longer support. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades for a guide how to do the upgrade from the command line.

Comment: I tried to upgrade it but it returns to me errors for me